# Suggested Edit notifications not being sent in a timely manner?

Tags: bug

I posted an answer and there was a suggested edit shortly after.  However I was not notified of the suggested edit via the message system until after it was approved.

The notification I got said that "An edit was suggested to your question(paraphrased)" just like it should but when I went to review it it had been approved 19 minutes before.

I have not problem with the edit(it was fixing a couple of grammar typos that were due to speed("you're" became "your" without me noticing) the question is why was I not notified about it as soon as it happened?  I know that it used to work that way.  As a result a someone else had to that the time to approve the edit that I could have taken care of immediately.

Yes I was online and paying attention to my notification system at the time as I received 4 comment notifications in that time.

I guess my question may be a bug report, as this behaviour is new, at least as far as I know...

If it matters or helps, the answer is [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/330973/65969)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is almost certainly a bug, as suggested edits should normally come to you as a notification the moment they are made.

It will be easier to track this problem if you notice it again, so if it happens again remember to update your report :)

Comment: ok thank you I will keep that in mind and will update the question if/when it happens again.